# Is it possible to allow NOPASSWD on an alias of a command requiring sudo?

Tags: command-line, sudo, alias

I added this alias:

```
alias shutdown2h='sudo shutdown -h +120'
```

which I would like to run without having to enter the password but also without adding NOPASSWD for the whole shutdown command.

Is it possible to add the alias to the sudoers file with the NOPASSWD alltogether? I tried it with the location of the command `~/.bash_aliases/shutdown2h` which gave me a syntax error.
Or is there another way?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process. Also read `man sudoers visudo`. Since the `alias` is replaced by the expansion by the parent shell before execution, `shutdown2h` doesn't get executed, `sudo shutdown -h +120` does.

Answer (score 3):

You want to ensure that your user is not able to make changes to what is being allowed to run.  For example, by attempting to add a script owned by your user (`~/.bash_aliases/shutdown2h`) to be run as root via `sudo` without a password, you would allow any arbitrary command to be run.  Simply edit that file and run it.  It would be the same as allowing the user to run any command via `sudoers`.  For example, the user would edit the file to read `now` instead of `-h +120` and shut down the machine immediately.

Instead, it would be a better idea to add a script owned by the root user to the system, probably in `/usr/local/bin/`.  For example, `/usr/local/bin/shutdown2h`, executable by everybody, but writable only by root.  This way, you ensure that the user can only run the specific script, and that script cannot be changed by them to run something else.  The path you place the script should be in your `$PATH`, which `/usr/local/bin` should be in by default.

1. Create the script

```
sudo vim /usr/local/bin/shutdown2h

#!/bin/bash
shutdown -h +120
```

2. Allow execution of the script

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/shutdown2h
```

3. Allow USER to run specific script

```
sudo visudo

# Add this entry
USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/shutdown2h
```

Now, your user can run `sudo shutdown2h` without being asked for a password and be sure that that user will only be able to run `shutdown -h +120` without a password.

Also, when making `sudoers` entries, be sure to provide the full path to the executable/script, and don't use any shortcuts like `~/` or `$HOME`.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: " probably in /usr/bin/": make that `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward solution without extra script is to:

1. create your alias:

```
alias shutdown2h='sudo shutdown -h +120'
```

2. allow this command to run without pw with:

```
sudo visudo
# Add this entry
someusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: shutdown -h +120
```

(Instead of sudo visudo, I prefer using `sudo visudo /etc/sudoers/someuserfile` and add the entry above in this new file. The advantage is that system upgrades that might overwrite the original sudo file will leave the configs in this file untouched.)

3. Run `shutdown2h` and it will work without pw.
   All other shutdown operations will require the same permissions as before.